# How do I solve word problems with systems of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

What strategy do I use to solve?  The difference of two numbers is 5. Their sum is 43. Find the numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You read the problem.  Often, as here, each sentence represents an equation.  Name the variables that seem to be important and write down the equations.  In this example, let the numbers be $x$ and $y$.  One sentence says $x-y=5$.  Can you write the other equation?  Can you solve the resulting set?

Answer (score 2):

Let the two numbers be $x$ and $y$.

1. $x - y = 5$

Therefore $x = y + 5$.

2. $x + y = 43$

Substitute: 
$$x + y = 43 \, \Rightarrow (y + 5) + y = 43$$

$$y = 19, \qquad x = 24$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,y$ be our numbers:

$$x-y=5$$

$$x+y=43$$

Summing up both equasions we get:

$$2x=48 \Rightarrow x=24$$

Placing $x$ in one of the equasions, we get $y=19$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let the numbers be $x$ and $y$ then form the equations and add both of them.